# Discord.JS v12 move to voice channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

Via **voiceStateUpdate** I track the movement of a user from one voice channel to another.
But how to catch the situation if someone dragged the user into another voice channel?

I tried to search in the server logs:

```
logs.entries.first().executor.id;
```

But in the case of an unauthorized transition and dragging, it gives the same thing.

---

I didn't get an answer. But I came up with my own way:

```
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldState, newState) => {
    let oldChannel = oldState.channel;
    let newChannel = newState.channel;
    let oldMember = oldState.member;
    let newMember = newState.member;

    if(oldState.channel && newState.channel && newChannel !== oldChannel) {
        //Get log
        newMember.guild.fetchAuditLogs().then(logs => {
            //Get first
            let firstEv = logs.entries.first();
            if (Date.now() - firstEv.createdTimestamp < 5000) {
                //dragging
            } else {
                //no dragging
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Hope it is useful to someone

Comment: If it is giving the same thing for multiple different events, it will just be down to the Discord API and if you are unable to distinguish between them then you will have to wait for it to be implemented/suggest it.

Comment: How can I track whether the user has switched to the voice channel or has someone dragged it?